# Custom Storage delete() method is not called in Django

Tags: python, django, storage

I have a field that inherits from ImageField with a custom storage like this:

```
image = PicasaImageField(upload_to=get_upload_to, blank=True, storage=pwcs())
```

When deleting an object with this field (using object.delete(), NOT bulk), the delete method of the custom storage doesn't get called. Trying to debug, I couldn't find where Django is going through the fields of an object to delete the file or whatever is behind in the actual storage. Or should I delete the file manually / in a hook / write a custom delete() method into my end model that will call the behind-the-stage delete() on the actual object? I failed to find how this is handled with the standard ImageFile + default filesystem, but would assume regular files would be deleted. Or am I getting it wrong?

Thanks for any insights.

Igor

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django 1.3 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.3/#deleting-a-model-doesn-t-delete-associated-files):

> when a model is deleted the FileField's delete() method won't be called. If you need cleanup of orphaned files, you'll need to handle it yourself

As you suggested you could handle this in a custom delete method:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    image.delete(save=False)
    super(Foo, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

or use a receiver function which will be called even when object.delete() is not called:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Foo, weak=False)
def delete_image_on_file(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    image.delete(save=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was missing.

Comment: @IgorR I'm glad that was what you were looking for and as such would you please mark it as the accepted answer?